# swift 5 Как внести словарь в аргументы функции

Tags: swift, xcode

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    func act(stru:[String:String]) {
        print(stru)
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
        var ButConnect : Bool = true
        var WordFrame = CGSize(width: 260, height: 260)
        var dict1 : Dictionary = ["Слово":"word"]
        var dict2 : [String:String] = ["Cat":"Кот"]
        
        // Кнопка
        var button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 50))
        button.backgroundColor = .green
        button.setTitle("Test Button", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction(dict1)), for: .touchUpInside)
        // Кнопка
        
        var but2 = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 300, y: 100, width: 100, height: 50))
        but2.backgroundColor = .green
        but2.setTitle("Test Button2", for: .normal)
        but2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonact2(dict2)), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(button)
        self.view.addSubview(but2)
    }

    @objc func buttonAction(dict: Dictionary, button:UIButton, sender: UIButton!) {
        act(dict)
    }
    @objc func buttonact2(dict: Dictionary, but2:UIButton, sender: UIButton) {
        act(dict)
    }

}
```

Comment: Что вы пытаетесь сделать и что не получается?

Comment: Добавьте описание к вопросу